# Write to excel file cell using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have an Excel file having some rows and 6 columns and in want to add a new column at 7th position named "Result". i am using Protractor and Node.js.Could somebody help me with the  code?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is support for appending data to an already existing file by the already existing NPM.

2.My solution to this is:

```
a)Read the excel file and convert to JSON.
 b)Add the new row(json) into that JSON.
 c)delete the old excel file.
 d)Recreate a excel file and write once again..
```

EDIT:

```
1.xlsx-to-json NPM look into this how to convert xlsx to json..
2.xlsx-writestream NPM to write into xlsx.
```

Go through the above ,you will get an idea..

Comment: thanks for the help as i am new  to this so could you please provide me some sample code.Help will be appreciated.